# EF 1 include for several children

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF 6 to query my database. I have a structure when I have a table (sites) which has 4 associated tables (wages, waste, sales & availability) linked by site ID.

The sub tables then all have an association to a departments table.

I have disabled lazy loading for performance reasons. I was wondering if there is a way to query the sites table where I can include the 4 sub tables but not need to specify the include to the department table for each of these.

Thanks

Comment: You can create an interface for the "four" objects then make an IncludeWithSite method that takes in input the interface then includes object and Site

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that simply adding an include to departments from one of the four tables (wages etc) was sufficent.